# How setting endianess works for DataView

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I'm reading [this explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) of DataView and there's an example there:

```
var littleEndian = (function() {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
  new DataView(buffer).setInt16(0, 256, true /* littleEndian */);
  // Int16Array uses the platform's endianness.
  return new Int16Array(buffer)[0] === 256;
})();
```

I don't really understand what this line does:

```
new DataView(buffer).setInt16(0, 256, true /* littleEndian */);
```

Does it mean that the data stored in the range `[0;256]` bits should be stored in littleEndian?

Comment: I think you want to look at the documentation for [`setInt16`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setInt16), where it tells you what the arguments for the function are.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I wan't interested in the arguments. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39846586/2545680).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we create an array buffer and array like this:

```
var dv = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));
```

It means that we've got 32 bits in memory:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now, we want to store the number `0x0103`, which has the pattern:

```
0000 0001 0000 0011
```

Now, let's store this number in first two bytes using little endianess, and in the second two bytes using big endianess and see how it's laid out in the memory. So:

```
dv.setInt16(0, 0x0103, true);
dv.setInt16(2, 0x0103, false);
```

Now, the bits in the `DataView` have this pattern:

```
0000 0011 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0011
```

Here is the code to test that behavior:

```
var little = dv.getUint16(0);
little === 0x0103 // false
little === 0x0301 // true

var big = dv.getUint16(2);
big === 0x0103 // true
big === 0x0301 // false
```